# SqlException was unhandled by user code. Directory lookup for the file .mdf failed with operating system error 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first

I've done the View and Model part in MVC 5, using Entity Framework Code-First. When i run my project, error points at this action in the Controller (specifically at the line i put with *)

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
        Using db As DbContext1 = New DbContext1()
            * Return View(db.food.ToList())
        End Using
End Function
```

The error is this:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users------\Visual Studio 2015\Projects------\App_Data---.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).

I've tried searching but couldn't find any solution to this. Anyone help me please. I've read that its happening probably because the project couldn't access the database. But when i clicked at Server Explorer->Data Connections->DatabaseName->Tables, everything is there.

After i Close Connection from the database in Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2015, i've also tried copying .mdf and .ldf file into C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER1\MSSQL\DATA, but error:

> "The action cannot be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program"

I've also tried running SQL Server as administrator and also tried Control Panel => Administrative Tools => Services => SQL Server => Properties => Logon and ensure my current user account have access to database, both didn't work as well. Same exception error as above.

**=== UPDATED ===**

I right-click the database >> Tasks >> Detach. I've also made sure that the database is not connected by any other mean (that means, Visual Studio, or any other application). And then i copied those files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER1\MSSQL\DATA . The copy works successfully but the problem is when i tried to attach back the database in SQL server, using both GUI and T-SQL Create Database query method, error below comes out:

> Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Could not open new database 'db'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
> Msg 948, Level 20, State 1, Line 1
> The database 'db' cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 706 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Comment: Are you sure running Visual Studio in Admin mode? (i.e., Run as administrator)?

Comment: I've just tried it but still the same outcome

Comment: try disconnecting the database in Server Explorer... I mean, in the server explorer - right-click your database and say "close connection". and then try running the application

Comment: Still same outcome

Comment: oh ok.. before trying to copy data to C:\Program Files... disconnect the database as I had suggested earlier... after that copy the db to that path and then run the application... or else if you want to keep the db on the same path, then you may need to give appropriate permission to the MDF and LDF files to allow you accessing the files (probably, give yourself full control on those files)

Comment: Check Administrative Tools => Services => SQL Server => Properties => Logon and ensure your current user account have access to database, also try run SQL Server as administrator. You may copy MDF-LDF file to `DATA` directory under MSSQL installation and attach it, then run EF query again.

Comment: @Nirman I tried your first suggestion, it didn't work. Give appropriate permission? If you mean by: right click on the mdf and ldf files -> properties -> Security tab -> Allow permission for user, then it didn't work as well..

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto My current user account does have access to the database. I also did run SQL server as administrator. From what you said "You may copy MDF-LDF file to DATA directory under MSSQL installation and attach it, then run EF query again." Is it different from what i mentioned in my question in the 3rd paragraph?

Comment: @Nurul - If you are still receiving an error while copying MDF and LDF files to the data folder, then its worth detaching the database from SQL Server Management Studio as well before trying to copy. That means, in your SSMS, right-click the database >> Tasks >> Detach. Also, make sure that the database is not connected by any other mean (that means, Visual Studio, or any other application). Now try copying those files, and see what happens!

Comment: @Nirman Wow! Thanks a lot! That mdf and ldf file copy worked! But the problem is when i tried to attach back the database, Right-click databases->Attach->Add->i chose .mdf file and after that i tried both .mdf and .ldf files, but both didn't work. Error: "An error occured when attaching the database(s). Click the hyperlink in the Message column for details."

Comment: @Nurul - glad to know the copy worked... what is the exact error message when you click on the hyperlink given in the error message. Also, make sure you running SSMS as an Administrator.

Comment: @Nurul - this seems to be a SQL Server versioning issue. Are you sure you are trying to attach to the same SQL Server instance from where you detached the database? 852 means, SQL Server 2016. Try running SELECT @@VERSION command in your SQL Server instance, and check the version.

Comment: Once you check the version of SQL Server instance, also check the version of MDF file by running following query in your SQL Server instance - DBCC CHECKPRIMARYFILE('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\SQLAuthority.mdf',2) -- You will need to replace the path of your database in the query

Comment: @Nirman yes, its from and to the same SQL server. I was surprised myself when i saw the error saying the error's due to different versions of SQL server. By the way, i can't find the SQL Server instance. where is it?

Comment: Its just the name of the sql server connected in SSMS

Comment: @Nirman Alright thanks. I've tried the last query you gave, the output is a column 'isMDF' with value 1. I retried the SELECT @@VERSION query, it worked now, and the output is 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)'